# how to upload a local postgres database to aws?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku

I don't understand how to import a local database to aws. I see : 'upload files' but how do I even get my database into a file?! Im so confused. 
I am trying to deploy my app with heroku so as I understand I have to first export it to (for example) was then from there to my heroku database and have found this command:

```
PGPASSWORD=mypassword pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump
```

Nothing really happens and I don't understand what password I am suppose to use..
Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload your PG database to Heroku, first you need to do `pg_dump` to export its contents (you basically have the right string above, I would try it without the "PGPASSWORD"; "mydb" is the name of your local database and "myuser" you can probably leave as "postgres"; "mydb.dump" is the name of the dump file that you'll want to upload to S3). Then you can upload it to AWS S3, make it public, and then pull it into Heroku with `heroku pg:backups restore 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/me/items/3H0q/mydb.dump' DATABASE_URL`. Here are the Heroku docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export.